# undefined method `keys' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, models

I have model order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer

    has_many :products, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'OrderProduct'
    has_many :attributes, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'OrderAttribute'
    has_one :invoice_address, class_name: 'OrderAddress'
    has_one :delivery_address, class_name: 'OrderAddress'

    validates :number, presence: true
    validates :total_amount, presence: true
end
```

When I run rspec i receive error

```
undefined method `keys' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

On line when I save order. When I comment out

```
    has_many :attributes, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'OrderAttribute'
```

It works as expected. My rspec file is:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe Order do
  before { @order = Order.new(:number => '132', :total_amount => 123, :paid_amount => 123) }

  it { assert_equal true, @order.valid? }

  describe "number cannot be empty" do
    before { @order.number = nil }
    it { assert_equal false, @order.valid? }
  end

  describe "total_amount cannot be nil" do
    before { @order.total_amount = nil }
    it { assert_equal false, @order.valid? }
  end

  describe "can add products" do
    before do
      @order.save
      @order.products.create(:name => 'test', :price => 123, :qty => 1)
    end

    it { assert_equal 1, @order.products.count }
  end

  # describe "can add attribute" do
  #   before do
  #     @order.save
  #     @order.attributes.create(:key => 'some_key', :value => '12')
  #   end

  #   it { assert_equal 1, @order.attributes.count }
  #   it { assert_equal 'some_key', @order.attributes.first.key }
  #   it { assert_equal '12', @order.attributes.first.value }
  # end
end
```

I comment out tests for order attributes, because it produces another errors. How to fix it?
I have order_comment.rb file with

```
class OrderAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
end
```

what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename `attributes` as that's what is causing you issues

> if you have a has_many called attributes, you can’t access to your
>   object attributes anymore; only the associated objects Original Rails
>   Wiki - additional words

Relevant link:

http://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/words/attributes